# Why my Next.js deployed app shows a blank page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I deployed my Next.js app on Vercel and its blank. It works fine locally.
On the browser console I can see this error:

```
_app-1516aa2c14264726.js:101 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
```

I do not see any error on my _app.js page with VSCode.
I do not know where to look and how to debug that.
When I enter a page url like [www.example.com/dashboards](http://www.example.com/dashboards) for exemple, I can see on Vercel, in the function logs, `[GET] /dashboards` without errors.

Here is my _app.js code:

```
    // ** Next Imports
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Router, useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';


// ** Store Imports
import { store } from 'src/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// ** Loader Import
import NProgress from 'nprogress';

// ** Emotion Imports
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';

// ** Config Imports
import 'src/configs/i18n';
import { defaultACLObj } from 'src/configs/acl';
import themeConfig from 'src/configs/themeConfig';

// ** Custom imports
import { 
  fetchAuthorizationAPI,
  getUser ,
} from 'components/Utils/apis';

// ** Fake-DB Import
import 'src/@fake-db';

// ** Third Party Import
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { hotjar } from 'react-hotjar';
import swell from 'swell-js';

// ** Component Imports
import UserLayout from 'src/layouts/UserLayout';
import AclGuard from 'src/@core/components/auth/AclGuard';
import ThemeComponent from 'src/@core/theme/ThemeComponent';
import AuthGuard from 'src/@core/components/auth/AuthGuard';
import GuestGuard from 'src/@core/components/auth/GuestGuard';
import WindowWrapper from 'src/@core/components/window-wrapper';

// ** Spinner Import
import Spinner from 'src/@core/components/spinner';

// ** Contexts
import { AuthProvider } from 'src/context/AuthContext';
import { SettingsConsumer, SettingsProvider } from 'src/@core/context/settingsContext';

// ** Styled Components
import ReactHotToast from 'src/@core/styles/libs/react-hot-toast';

// ** Utils Imports
import { createEmotionCache } from 'src/@core/utils/create-emotion-cache';

// ** Prismjs Styles
import 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-jsx';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-tsx';

// ** React Perfect Scrollbar Style
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';

// ** Global css styles
import '../../styles/globals.css';

//SEO, Cookies, Translation
//import { DefaultSeo } from 'next-seo';
import { parseCookies } from 'nookies';

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();
//const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const { HJID } = process.env;
const { HJSV } = process.env;
const { SWELL_STORE_ID } = process.env;
const { NEXT_PUBLIC_SWELL_PK } = process.env;

// ** Pace Loader
if (themeConfig.routingLoader) {
  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
    NProgress.start()
  })
  Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
    NProgress.done()
  })
  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
    NProgress.done()
  })
}

const Guard = ({ children, authGuard, guestGuard }) => {
  try{
    if (guestGuard) {
      return <GuestGuard fallback={<Spinner />}>{children}</GuestGuard>
    } else if (!guestGuard && !authGuard) {
      return <>{children}</>
    } else {
      return <AuthGuard fallback={<Spinner />}>{children}</AuthGuard>
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log('eerr', err)
  }
}

// ** Configure JSS & ClassName
const App = props => {

 
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps, auth_user, token } = props

  // ** Hooks
  const router = useRouter()

  // Variables
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? (page => <UserLayout>{page}</UserLayout>)
  const setConfig = Component.setConfig ?? undefined
  const authGuard = Component.authGuard ?? true
  const guestGuard = Component.guestGuard ?? false
  const aclAbilities = Component.acl ?? defaultACLObj

  useEffect(() => {
    //ReactGA.initialize(`${NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`);
    //ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  
  },[])
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    hotjar.initialize(HJID, HJSV);
    swell.init(SWELL_STORE_ID, NEXT_PUBLIC_SWELL_PK);
  }, []);
  
  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <Head>
          <title>{`${themeConfig.templateName} - Dashboard`}</title>
          <meta
            name='description'
            content={`${themeConfig.templateName} – Template !`}
          />
          <meta name='keywords' content='E-commerce' />
          <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1, width=device-width' />
        </Head>
        <AuthProvider>
          <SettingsProvider {...(setConfig ? { pageSettings: setConfig() } : {})}>
            <SettingsConsumer>
              {({ settings }) => {
                return (
                  <ThemeComponent settings={settings}>
                    <WindowWrapper>
                      <Guard authGuard={authGuard} guestGuard={guestGuard}>
                        <AclGuard aclAbilities={aclAbilities} guestGuard={guestGuard}>
                          {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} auth_user={auth_user} token={token} router={router} />)}
                        </AclGuard>
                      </Guard>
                    </WindowWrapper>
                    <ReactHotToast>
                      <Toaster position={settings.toastPosition} toastOptions={{ className: 'react-hot-toast' }} />
                    </ReactHotToast>
                  </ThemeComponent>
                )
              }}
            </SettingsConsumer>
          </SettingsProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </Provider>
  )
}

App.getInitialProps = async({ctx}) => {

  const token = parseCookies(ctx).jwt

  const userRes = token ? await fetchAuthorizationAPI(getUser, token, 'runtime') : null
  const userData = userRes && await userRes;
 
return { 
    auth_user: userData, 
    token: token       
    
  }
} 

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't have a clue but isn't Next server side rendered? Are you sure your host can handle that or is it expecting a SPA or static site?

Comment: Yes it can handle that, it's a dashboard from Material UI (Materio) that I modified, it was made for Next.js and it was working until I made a few changes. Unfortunately, I do not know which one provoked that.

Comment: Since your app probably loads all your content your site provides the issue does not necessarily need to be in the app component itself. If you really don't know where the issue is I would start commenting out each thing that it renders until it starts working again and then debug the piece that's actually causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @Micky's recommandation and I discovered that I had a setting on my next.config.js file that caused this error. I removed this line bellow and now it is working angain,

```
swcMinify: true,
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

in my case
after many hours of trying every methods
believe me , every methods

it was my google chrome version
i updated and its work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).